# How to group by column and a fixed time window/frequency

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

**EDIT**: My main goal is not to use a for loop and find a way of grouping the data efficiently/fast.

I am trying to solve a problem, which is about grouping together different rows of data based on an ID and a time window of 30 Days.

I have the following example data:

| ID | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-01-29 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-15 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-16 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-03-15 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-04-24 14:00:00 |
| 12344 | 2021-01-24 14:00:00 |
| 12344 | 2021-01-25 14:00:00 |
| 12344 | 2021-04-24 14:00:00 |

And I would like to have the following data:

| ID | Time | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-01-01 14:00:00 | 1 |
| 12345 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 | 1 |
| 12345 | 2021-01-29 14:00:00 | 1 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-15 14:00:00 | 2 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-16 14:00:00 | 2 |
| 12345 | 2021-03-15 14:00:00 | 3 |
| 12345 | 2021-04-24 14:00:00 | 4 |
| 12344 | 2021-01-24 14:00:00 | 5 |
| 12344 | 2021-01-25 14:00:00 | 5 |
| 12344 | 2021-04-24 14:00:00 | 6 |

(4 can also be 1 as it is in a new group based on the ID 12344; 5 can also be 2)
I could differentiate then based on the ID column. So the Group does not need to be unique but can be.

The most important would be to separate it based on the ID and then check all the rows for each ID and assign an ID to the 30 Days time window. By 30 Days time window I mean that e.g. the first time frame for ID 12345 starts at 2021-01-01 and goes up to 2021-01-31 (this should be the group 1) and then the second time time frame for the ID 12345 starts at 2021-02-01 and would go to 2021-03-02 (for 30 days).

The problem I have faced with using the following code is that it uses the first date it finds in the dataframe:

```
grouped_data = df.groupby(["ID",pd.Grouper(key = "Time", freq = "30D")]).count()
```

In the above code I have just tried to count the rows (which wouldn't give me the Group, but I have tried to group it with my logic).

I hope someone can help me with this, because I have tried so many different things and nothing did work. I have already used the following (but maybe wrong):

- pd.rolling()
- pd.Grouper()
- for loop
- etc.

I really don't want to use for loop as I have 1.5 Mio rows.
And I have tried to vectorize the for loop but I am not really familiar with vectorization and was struggling to transfer my for loop to a vectorization.

Please let me know if I can use pd.Grouper differently so I get the results. thanks in advance.

Comment: @SeaBean: You have any thoughts about solving this grouping problem?

Comment: @SeaBean Thanks :) 
I have also tought about applying the following logic:

create column of time difference (timedelta) between the previous row (the df must be sorted by ID and Time so I get the right order) and then a second column which calculates the cumulative sum of the time_difference over the ID => requirement: Every time the cum sum hits 30 or above it needs to reset the cum sum calculation.

Then I create logic which says => At every breakpoint (where the cum sum resets) I assign negative ID (-1,-2,-3,etc.). Then I replace all the positive values with NaN and ffill down the df.

Comment: @SeaBean: Yes that was the difficulty in advance, but I have figured out that I do not have to reset the cum sum. I have used the following logic:

1. Order by ID and Time
2. Create column with time difference between the recent Time and previous per ID
3. Transfrom timedelta64[ns] to timedelta64[D]
4. Calculate the cum sum per ID (I do not need to reset cum sum)
4. Divide the cum sum by 30 (as integer)

With this I get the bins correctly. Then I only need to fill the dataset from end to start for the NaN values. NaN exists for the first entry per ID by calculating the time difference.

Comment: I had also thought of this logics to subdivide the dates  into equal fixed bins sometimes ago.  If this were feasible then your dates are not as dynamic as you described.  Remember your data need to group 2021-02-15 together with 2021-03-15 ?  If we have a date of 2021-01-01 to start the first bin for the first id, then the 2nd bin starts at 2021-02-01 (or 2021-01-31), then 2021-02-15 will be in 2nd bin.  How about 2021-03-15 ?  You make it in bin 3, according to this 30 days bin ?   But your original requirement was to count them in the same group 2, right ?

Comment: The problem of this 30 day bin will only fix the bin start date rather than allowing dynamic bin with bin start as the first date of a dates series detached from previous group.

Comment: @SeaBean: 
But the divide by 30 logic eliminates the problem.

The first bin of my sampleData starts at 2021-01-01 for the ID 12345 right?
This bin ends on the 2021-01-31. So the first 3 rows are in bin 1.

The second bin of my sampleData starts at 2021-02-15.
This bin ends on the 2021-03-17. So row 4-6 are in one bin.

So a bin starts always with the date which is the first one which is not in the previous bin (grouped by ID). If you now divide by 30 you will always stay on the same integer for the 30 day time window.

Comment: @SeaBean:
Maybe there is a better solution but it worked for me and it only need 53 seconds for running on 1.5 mio rows and the result is correct :) 

Please share if you found another way :)

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary windows you can use `pandas.cut`

eg, for 30 day bins starting at `2021-01-01 00:00:00` for the entirety of 2021 you can use:

```
bins =  pd.date_range("2021", "2022", freq="30D")
group = pd.cut(df["Time"], bins)
```

`group` will label each row with an interval which you can then group on etc.  If you want the groups to have labels 0, 1, 2, etc then you can map values with:

```
dict(zip(group.unique(), range(group.nunique())))
```

EDIT: approach where the windows are 30 day intervals, disjoint, and starting at a time in the `Time` column:

```
times = df["Time"].sort_values()
ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(times, times+pd.Timedelta("30 days"))

disjoint_intervals = []
prev_interval = None

for i, interval in enumerate(ii):
    if prev_interval is None or interval.left >= prev_interval.right:  # no overlap
        prev_interval = interval 
        disjoint_intervals.append(i)

bins =  ii[disjoint_intervals]
group = pd.cut(df["Time"], bins)
```

Apologies, this is not a vectorised approach.  Struggling to think if one could exist.

Comment: There is no fixed bin start date for the entire data.  A new bin whenever the previous group ends and the bin start is based on the first date of the new bin, not the 1st of the month or whatever fixed.

Comment: @SeaBean: Yes that is correct. The first date of the 30 Days time window is based on the new bin. That's why the first date would need to be dynamically.

Comment: Ah ok, the `bins` argument can be an IntervalIndex, so if we have a way of efficiently calculating the windows then it can save this approach

Comment: I think so yes.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION**:
The solution which worked for me is the following:

I have imported the sampleData from excel into a dataframe. The data looks like this:

| ID | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-01-29 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-15 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-02-16 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-03-15 14:00:00 |
| 12345 | 2021-04-24 14:00:00 |
| 12344 | 2021-01-24 14:00:00 |
| 12344 | 2021-01-25 14:00:00 |
| 12344 | 2021-04-24 14:00:00 |

Then I have used the following steps:

1. Import the data:

```
df_test = pd.read_excel(r"sampleData.xlsx")
```

2. Order the dataframe so we have the correct order of ID and Time:

```
df_test_ordered = df_test.sort_values(["ID","Time"])
df_test_ordered = df_test_ordered.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I have also reset the index and dropped it as it has manipulated my calculations later on.

3. Create column with time difference between the previous row:

```
df_test_ordered.loc[df_test_ordered["ID"] == df_test_ordered["ID"].shift(1),"time_diff"] = df_test_ordered["Time"] - df_test_ordered["Time"].shift(1)
```

4. Transform timedelta64[ns] to timedelta64[D]:

```
df_test_ordered["time_diff"] = df_test_ordered["time_diff"].astype("timedelta64[D]")
```

5. Calculate the cumsum per ID:

```
df_test_ordered["cumsum"] = df_test_ordered.groupby("ID")["time_diff"].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

6. Backfill the dataframe (exchange the NaN values with the next value):

```
df_final = df_test_ordered.ffill().bfill()
```

7. Create the window by dividing by 30 (30 days time period):

```
df_final["Window"] = df_final["cumsum"] / 30
df_final["Window_int"] = df_final["Window"].astype(int)
```

The "Window_int" column is now a kind of ID (not unique; but unique within the groups of column "ID").

Furthermore, I needed to backfill the dataframe as there were NaN values due to the calculation of time difference only if the previous ID equals the ID. If not then NaN is set as time difference. Backfilling will just set the NaN value to the next time difference which makes no difference mathematically and assign the correct value.

Solution dataframe:

```
      ID                Time  time_diff  cumsum    Window  Window_int
0  12344 2021-01-24 14:00:00        1.0     1.0  0.032258           0
1  12344 2021-01-25 14:00:00        1.0     1.0  0.032258           0
2  12344 2021-04-24 14:00:00       89.0    90.0  2.903226           2
3  12345 2021-01-01 14:00:00       14.0    14.0  0.451613           0
4  12345 2021-01-15 14:00:00       14.0    14.0  0.451613           0
5  12345 2021-01-29 14:00:00       14.0    28.0  0.903226           0
6  12345 2021-02-15 14:00:00       17.0    45.0  1.451613           1
7  12345 2021-02-16 14:00:00        1.0    46.0  1.483871           1
8  12345 2021-03-15 14:00:00       27.0    73.0  2.354839           2
9  12345 2021-04-24 14:00:00       40.0   113.0  3.645161           3
```

Comment: See my latest comments in the question.  So, could you group 2021-02-15 and 2021-03-15 in the same group by this logics ?  Given, the first date in the same id is 2021-01-01.

Comment: @SeaBean: Yes :)

Comment: Haven't yet run your codes, but I wonder why Feb 15 being around day 45 form Jan 1, could be in the same bin of March 15 being around day 75 from Jan 1.  45 and 75 should give different whole numbers when divided by 30, right ?   May need to go in deeper checking your code if you get them in the same group.

Comment: @SeaBean:
Sorry I have misscalculated. You are right I do not catch the 15.03.2021 in the same bin as with 15.02.2021. As the time difference of the two dates are 27 days.

But the logic I have used is correct for my scenario, I have only set the Group incorrect in my answer. 

Sorry about that :/

Comment: What do you mean by the logic you used is correct for your scenario ?  You don't need to cater for the case of 15.03.2021 in same bin as 15.02.2021 ?   If your requirement is actually simpler and not requiring so much dynamic binning (ie. first date of a date detached from previous will be the bin start), I suggest you edit your question to the simpler case so that future readers won't be misguided for the solution.

Comment: I already have adjusted it

Comment: You adjusted the values in expected output but the description still remains with this:  `the second time time frame for the ID 12345 starts at 2021-02-15 and would go to 2021-03-15.`   Please remove it also.